# Size or level $ \alpha $ in Neyman-Pearson

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference

I found two different definitions of [Neyman-Person lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma), one using the size $ \alpha $ and one the level $ \alpha $ of a test.
I know the two concepts are related, but not synonymous.

Is the lemma the same in both cases? Does it make any difference in the proof?

Comment: Yes, the lemma is the same in both cases.  The answer lies in the definition of "size" and "level."  Suppose we wish to test $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$  vs  $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$.

Let the test of hypothesis be $\phi(X) = I(\Lambda(X) < k)$  An alpha **size** test is such that $E_{\theta_0}(\phi(X)) = \alpha$ whereas an alpha **level** test is such that $E_{\theta_0}(\phi(X)) \le \alpha$, so if the NP-Lemma satisfies all alpha level tests, and alpha size tests are a subset of alpha level tests, then NP-Lemma applies to both cases.

Comment: @Lewkrr: This looks like an answer, can you make it into one? (in the answer box)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the lemma is the same in both cases. The answer lies in the definition of "size" and "level."

Suppose we wish to test $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:θ>θ_0$. Let the test of hypothesis be $ϕ(X)=I(Λ(X)<k)$

An alpha **size** test is such that $E_{θ_0}(ϕ(X))=α$ whereas an alpha **level** test is such that $E_{θ_0}(ϕ(X))≤α$

So, if the NP-Lemma satisfies all alpha level tests, and alpha *size* tests are a subset of alpha *level* tests, then the NP-Lemma applies to both cases.